# Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k} $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k} $

### My attempt

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \\
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{k-n-1}{k} = \\
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{k-n-1}{-n-1} $$
now let $$ s:= -n - 1 = const $$

so
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{k-n-1}{-n-1}  = \\
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2k+1}\binom{k+s}{s}
$$

And there I stucked.
I was thinking if I can use that formula:
$$ \sum_k \binom{k}{m} = \binom{n+1}{m+1} $$
but $ \frac{1}{2k+1}$ is an obstacle for me. How I can "remove" that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^{2k}$$

Integrate both sides wrt $x$

Set $x=0$ to find the constant of integration

Then $x^2=-1$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225996/recurrence-relation-for-the-integral-i-n-int-fracdx1x2n

Comment: I can't use integrals there. (Btw, downvote is not from me)